# "Prefix not Found" and HiveConf ClassNotFoundException on Zeppelin Tutorial

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am attempting to run the preinstalled `Zeppelin Tutorial`. None of the `%sql` or `%r` entries work: they all say either ***Prefix not Found*** or throw `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf

`%sql` broken:

[image]

`%R` broken:

[image]

These errors happen for untouched / clean install Zeppelin. They continue to happen even after I pointed to a separate `spark` installation that I know contains hive.  Anyone figure these things out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error ,it seems can't find the package, i have encountered the same situation when i used Spark Interpreter to read data from HBase in the Zeppelin .I solved the problem by adding dependencies in the Interpreter setting page .[image: add dependencies]

May be you can add dependencies which can't find in this page ,hope it helpful.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'm just surprised that key spark classes are missing.